# Where are the "curl libraries?"

Tags: haskell, curl, config, ghc, cabal-install

I tried to install curl, the haskell package like so:

```
cabal install curl
```

The relevant error is:

```
configure: error: curl libraries not found, so curl package cannot be built
```

**Where are these "curl libraries?"** I already have curl the program on my computer (a Ubuntu  13.04 box.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to install the development files for `curl`. If you are on Ubuntu Linux, then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

And then do the normal cabal installation of `curl` as usual.

Comment: I wish Cabal/Stack made this more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Search in your package manager for libcurl. libcurl is the library required for the installation, and once install should be located in /usr/lib. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is no package called "libcurl" but I do have "libcurl3". It is not in /usr/lib. Do have anything I could do?

Comment: its the same thing. libcurl3 is precisely the third major version of the curl libraries